# Gortimer Gibbon's Wife

Tags: character, ending, gortimer-gibbons-life

In the ending of **Gortimer Gibbon's Life on Normal Street** *"Gortimer vs. the End"* an animation was shown of what becomes of the trio and their friends.

At one point he breaks up with a girl but I can't figure out who it was supposed to be because it's all animated. Then he gets married to another girl that looked similar to the girl he broke up with.

Was she a character in the series, an old friend? Or was she an entirely different character that wasn't in the series only on the ending story?